# MVC3 Cascading Dropdown with JQuery to Populate Sublist on Edit

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a working cascading dropdown in create view with this javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#GaCatId").change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON("/Gallery/GetSubCategories/", { id: id },
        function (data) {
            var select = $("#GaSCatId");
            select.empty();
            select.append($('<option/>', {
                value: 0,
                text: "Select a Sub Category"
            }));
            $.each(data, function (index, data) {

                select.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: data.Value,
                    text: data.Text
                }));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I want to edit this  so that on Edit  razor View it will populate the sublist based on the default ID record in database. In effect I am looking making the code check if there is an ID

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to check whether the firstdropdowns selected item value and if it is valid, make another ajax call to get the data for the second dropdown and load it.
Assuming you have the 2 dropdowns exist in the page,

```
$(function(){

  var gaCatId=$("#gaCatId").val();  
  if(gaCatId!="") 
  {
     var items="";
     $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetSubCategories","Gallery")/"+gaCatId,
                                                                 function(data){
           $.each(data, function (index, item) {
             items+="<option value='"+item.Value+"'>"+item.Text+"</option>";
           });
        $("#GaSCatId").html(items);
     });
  }   

});
```

This should work. **But if it is an EDIT screen, Why not load this from the action method itself ?** I would do that.

Assuming you are editing a Product page. So you may have a viewmodel like this

```
public class ProductVM
{
  public int ID {  set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Categories { set;get;} 
  public List<SelectListItem> SubCategories { set;get;}
  public int SelectedCategoryID { set;get;}
  public int SelectedSubCategoryID { set;get;}
}
```

in your edit GET action method,

```
public ActinResult Edit(int id)
{
  var vm=new ProductVM { ID=id};
  Product product=repo.GetProductFromID(id);
  vm.Name=product.Name;
  vm.Categories=GetAvailableCategories();
  vm.SelectedCategoryID=product.Category.ID;
  vm.SubCategories=GetSubCategories(product.Category.ID);
  vm.SelectedCategoryID=product.SubCategory.ID;
  return View(vm);
}
```

Assuming `GetAvailableCategories` and `GetSubCategories` are 2 methods which returns a list of `SelectListItem`

```
private List<SelectListItem> GetAvailableCategories()
{
  //TO DO : read from repositary and build the list and return.
}
```

and in your view which is strongly typed to our ProductVM class

```
@model ProductVM
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ID)
   @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Name)
   @Html.DropDownListfor(x=>x.SelectedCategoryID ,
                                      Model.Categories,"select")
   @Html.DropDownListfor(x=>x.SelectedSubCategoryID,
                                      Model.SubCategories,"select")
  <input type="submit" />

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt response and the alternative  workable solution.  I have tried the JavaScript function but that does not yield the result.  Am I to add it to the original code that works with the create view or I should replace it with your suggested code?

Comment: i personally recommend you to do the second approach which is load data in the edit view and show it.